# Concatenate different fields with different seperator

Tags: text-processing, paste

I have a tab delimited file like this:

```
chr1    53736473        54175786
chr1    56861276        56876438
chr1    57512145        57512200
```

I want to concatenate the three fields result like this:

```
chr1:53736473-54175786
chr1:56861276-56876438
chr1:57512145-57512200
```

I tried with `paste -d ':-' file`, which apparently didn't work. Could anyone help?

Ideally could be with simple unix command, I know it is rather easy with higher language.

Comment: sorry, that was embarrassing, I fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t/\1:\2-/' file

chr1:53736473-54175786
chr1:56861276-56876438
chr1:57512145-57512200
```

printf:

```
printf "%s:%s-%s\n" $(< file)

chr1:53736473-54175786
chr1:56861276-56876438
chr1:57512145-57512200
```

Comment: That awk command is also elegant.

Comment: `sed 's/\t\(\S\+\)\t/:&-/' file` much simple

Comment: @Costas You probably mean `\1`, not `&`: `sed 's/\t\(\S\+\)\t/:\1-/'`. Yes, it is shorter.

Comment: @jimmij I've made mistake, thank you for correction.

Answer (score 5):

For your example,

```
awk '{print $1":"$2"-"$3}' your_file
```

will work, but it assumes you will always have exactly 3 fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `sed` expressions:

```
sed -e "s/\t/,/" -e "s/\t/-/" your_file
```

Answer (score 2):

With `paste` and `printf`:

```
$ printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' $(cat file) | paste -sd ':-\n' -
chr1:53736473-54175786
chr1:56861276-56876438
chr1:57512145-57512200
```